# Creating a custom Store in a view initComponent yields to "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined"

Tags: extjs

I have been using extjs for only 3 days now so I am very new and am trying to get used to some of the concepts.

I have a view called GroupListView which contains multiple GroupViews.  Each group view needs to instantiate a ContactStore and invoke an ajax call with the groupId to get all the contacts in that group.  So, I thought I can put a var contactStore = Ext.Create('MyApp.store.ContactStore'); in to the initComponent of the GroupView component (remember I don't want a singleton - each group has its own contact data).

It throws an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined" error when I do that.  If you remove that line things are fine but obviously I have no contact data.

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/5gv

What am I doing wrong?  And once I get this working, what is the best practice to get the groupId from the GroupView in the example (so I can pass it in the ajax call to the restful service)?  Is it to set a local property, like I do, called groupData in the GroupStore load loop I have?  Is there a better way to automatically create a GroupView components for all the items in the GroupStore, like a repeater kind of thing, rather than my manual loop?

If you can kindly just give me a general "yes - you're on the right path" or "no you're doing things not the extjs way" I'd appreciate it.  Yes - I realize I am missing controllers :)

Thanks

Comment: `Ext.create`, lower case c.

Comment: wow - yeah - that's embarrassing :)  Thanks

Comment: So - "yes - you're on the right path" now :)

Comment: Well - actually - my question about the right path, doesn't pertain to fixing the Ext.Create.  I am more interested in whether using the initComponent event to load the data store and then looping through the data store items in the load event and instantiating and adding child components to the parent one is a good practice.